# Is there a working version of Cisco's QtWebdriver and Selenium 4?

Tags: python, qt, selenium-webdriver, selenium-remotedriver

After upgrading to Selenium 4 I cannot create a Remote Webdriver in Python3.11 to connect to our QT Application using the [qtwebdriver](https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver).

I have been able to connect to our CEF Application and Android Tablet using Selenium 4.9.1 and Appium 2.0.0-beta.71 respectively.

I have tried creating a Remote Webdriver with the options but I receive an error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Missing or invalid 'desiredCapabilities'`

I know the desired capabilities were deprecated and I am guessing the [capabilities parser](https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/blob/WD_1.X_dev/src/webdriver/webdriver_capabilities_parser.cc) does not work with the options.

https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-4-features

> In Selenium 4, capabilities objects are replaced with Options. This means testers now need to create an Options object, set test requirements, and pass the object to the Driver constructor.

---

**Is there a working version of Cisco's QtWebdriver and Selenium 4?**